# Hash join clarity needed

Tags: join, hash, hashmap, data-modeling

The definition states

> Hash join is used when projections of the joined tables are not
> already sorted on the join columns. In this case, the optimizer builds
> an in-memory hash table on the inner table's join column. The
> optimizer then scans the outer table for matches to the hash table,
> and joins data from the two tables accordingly.

So table A is hashed and table B not. So how can we compare a hashed value with a non-hashed value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) (of any kind) do not make comparisons between hashed and unhashed values.

Hash tables (of any kind) use a hash of the key to determine the (small) bucket into which to place the *actual* key (here, the FK value) and the key's value (here, the row). The hash is used to deterministically, but evenly, evenly distribute entries across the buckets, with the goal of minimising the maximum number of entries in all buckets.

By keeping the bucket sizes (the number of entries per bucket) small by dynamically resizing the number of buckets, hash tables make for remarkably fast retrieval, because once the bucket is found, there are few entries to traverse in the entries found there to find the hit (or not).

Hash tables are so fast they are considered to have constant time operations - ie the time to find/add an entry is constant no matter how many entries (here, rows) are stored in it.

Comment: `scans the outer table for matches to the hash table`. What does this match mean?

Comment: It means "get the key of the inner table from the outer table FK (or FK like) column, then retrieve the inner table row from the hash table using that key, and in the course of that retrieval the hash of the key will be used to locate the bucket the entry will be found in". The bucket number is the remainder of dividing the hash of the key by the number of buckets - after that calculation, the hash is discarded.